# Producing a column with rotated text in all cells

Tags: tables, rotating, tabularx

I would like to set the first and the second column of the shown `tabularx` table to automatically rotate any text inside a single cell of one row or a single cell consisting of cells joined by `\multirow` and to center it both vertically and horizontally while allowing to adjust the height of the columns by `\\[height]` or other method with top vertical alignment of the content.

*Just to explain the rule through the first column, I also need `\noalign{\hrule height 1pt}` to behave like `\cline{2-4}`, hence not affecting the first column, but that is for another question, I guess.*

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\scriptsize
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{0.2em}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{!{\vrule width 1pt} p{0.3cm} !{\vrule width 1pt} p{0.5cm} | p{4cm} | X !{\vrule width 1pt}}
\noalign{\hrule height 1pt}
\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Ten}}&\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Eight}} & One & Two\\[0.5cm] \cline{3-4}
& & Three & Four\\[1cm] \noalign{\hrule height 1pt}
&\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Nine}} & Five & Six\\[0.5cm] \cline{3-4}
& & \multicolumn{2}{ l !{\vrule width 1pt}}{Seven}\\[1cm]
\noalign{\hrule height 1pt}
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image: The current state.]

**Fig. 1:** The current state.

[image: The objective.]

**Fig. 2:** The approximate objective (digitally manipulated in a graphics editing program).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- You could use an option for customizing the origin of the rotation, such as `\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{...}`
- The manually added vertical space at the end of the rows destroys the aligment. see how it looks without:

  ```
  \documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
  \usepackage{lmodern}
  \usepackage{array}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{multirow}
  \usepackage{tabularx}
  \begin{document}

  \scriptsize
  \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0.2em}
  \noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{!{\vrule width 1pt}
      p{0.3cm} !{\vrule width 1pt} p{0.5cm} | p{4cm} | X !{\vrule
      width 1pt}}
  \noalign{\hrule height 1pt}
  \multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Ten}}&
      \multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Eight}}
      & One & Two\\\cline{3-4}
  & & Three & Four\\\cline{2-4}
  &\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Nine}}
  & Five & Six\\ \cline{3-4}
  & & \multicolumn{2}{ l !{\vrule width 1pt}}{Seven}\\
  \noalign{\hrule height 1pt}
  \end{tabularx}

  \end{document}
  ```

[image]

- If you make such manual adjustments, which `multirow` doesn't know about, you can use the optional `fixup` argument of `\multirow` for correction:

  ```
  \multirow{nrows}[bigstruts]{width}[fixup]{text}
  ```
- For automatic rotating, I would use `>{...}` and `>{...}` of the `array` package together with a `sideways` environment of the `rotating` package, such as

  ```
  >{\begin{sideways}}p{0.3cm}<{\end{sideways}}
  ```

or even define a new column type for it:

```
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\begin{sideways}}p{#1}<{\end{sideways}}}
```

Here's the example showing automatic rotation, but without multirow, since this would not work as intended as it's applied after rotation:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\begin{sideways}}p{#1}<{\end{sideways}}}
\begin{document}
\scriptsize
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{0.2em}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{!{\vrule width 1pt}
    R{0.3cm} !{\vrule width 1pt} R{0.5cm} | p{4cm} | X !{\vrule
    width 1pt}}
\noalign{\hrule height 1pt}
Ten & Eight
& One & Two\\\cline{3-4}
& & Three & Four\\\cline{2-4}
& Nine
& Five & Six\\ \cline{3-4}
& & \multicolumn{2}{ l !{\vrule width 1pt}}{Seven}\\
\noalign{\hrule height 1pt}
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am using `\multirow{4}{*}{...}` only where I need it (see Fig. 2). I know it works without the height adjustment, but I need it. I did not know about the `fixup` argument, though. I shall try it and then report. However, this is still not a solution as I need the column to rotate the content _automatically_.

Comment: @Harrold: I see, corrected. Just Fig. 1 led me to think there were 2 rows to span.

Comment: It is not exactly what I hoped for but certainly useful for situations without the need to adjust the height of columns, thank you.