# How can I align rotated text in a table at the bottom?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, rotating

I have a code that produces a table. The three last columns have rotated text. I would like to align them to the bottom (not top as in the code below). In addition I would like to center the "nr" and "NAME" columns both vertically and horizontally in the cell they occupy. Can somebody please help me to achieve this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{sidewaystable}

\begin{tabular}{|l|m{10cm}|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|r|r|r|}
\hline
nr. & NAME & DATE: & & & & & & & & &
& & & & & \multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{POINTS}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{QUALITY}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{PLACE}} \\ [0.6cm]
\cline{3-16}
& & ROUND: & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & & & \\ [0.6cm]
\hline
1 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\hline
2 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\hline
3 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\hline
4 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\hline
5 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\hline
6 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\hline
7 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\hline
8 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\hline
9 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\hline
10 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\hline
11 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\hline
12 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\hline
13 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\hline
14 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the second optional argument of `\multirow` to fine tune the position:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{sidewaystable}

\begin{tabular}{|l|m{10cm}|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|r|r|r|}
\hline
\multirow{5}{*}{nr.} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{5}{*}{NAME}} & DATE: & & & & & & & & &
& & & & & 
\multirow{2}{*}[-17.5pt]{\rotatebox{90}{POINTS}} 
& \multirow{2}{*}[-9pt]{\rotatebox{90}{QUALITY}} & \multirow{2}{*}[-21pt]{\rotatebox{90}{PLACE}} \\ [0.6cm]
\cline{3-16}
& & ROUND: & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & & & \\ [0.6cm]
\hline
1 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
\hline
2 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
\hline
3 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
\hline
4 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
\hline
5 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
\hline
6 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
\hline
7 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
\hline
8 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
\hline
9 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
\hline
10 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
\hline
11 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
\hline
12 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
\hline
13 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
\hline
14 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That solved the first problem. Did you experiment to find the right numbers (-17.5pt, -9pt and -21pt)? Do you know how to center the "nr." and "NAME" both vertically and horizontally?

Comment: use `\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering}m{#1}}` and change `m{10cm}` to `M{10cm}` to get closer to centering

Comment: @chessaddict my bad. I didn't read carefully your question, so I overlooked the second requirement. I've updated my answer; it is something like that what you need? And, yes, the values for the second argument were determined "manually".

Comment: Then it is centered horizontally, but not vertically. Is it possible to do vertically as well?

Comment: Thank you Gonzalo. My comment was to cmhughes. Gonzalo your last edit made my day. Thanks for your very quick response! It is working as specified now.

Comment: Any tricks for getting the labels *not upside down but upright* in the last columns?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse if I understand your request, you can simply not use the `\rotatebox` commands and just `\multirow`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina no, then they're rotated left. Look at "PLACE" in the picture. I tried `\rotatebox{-90}` but then the layout is broken.

Comment: See also http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=2990, http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24550/8272 for the option `\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{...}`.