# How to horizontally align rotated text in a table?

Tags: tables, macros, align, rotating

I am trying to horizontally align text that has been rotated in a table. I want the rotated "Lorem Ipsum" and the rotated "Lorem Ipsum & Lorem Ipsum" text to be horizontally centered in the cell. When I adjust the width of each column manually, the alignment is no longer centered. I need to modify the width of each column so that my table will fit in the width of a single column.

I tried using the `\multirow` command from [How can I align rotated text in a table at the bottom?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69708/table-rotated-text-alignment) but I was only able to modify the vertical alignment.

Here is what my table looks like:

[image: Table]

Here is the code (apologies if I included some unnecessary packages):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\RotText[1]{\fontsize{9}{9}\selectfont \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\parbox{2.6cm}{\centering#1}}}
\newcolumntype{G}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.0625cm}}
\newcolumntype{U}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.375cm}}

{\centering
\begin{center}\begin{table}[ht]\caption{Lorem Ipsum Table}
\footnotesize
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|G|U|U|U|U|G|G|G|U|}
\hline
 & \multicolumn{9}{c|}{Lorem Ipsum} \\ 
\cline{2-10}

Instruction & \RotText{Lorem Ipsum} & \RotText{Lorem Ipsum \& Lorem Ipsum} & \RotText{Lorem Ipsum \& Lorem Ipsum} & \RotText{Lorem Ipsum \& Lorem Ipsum} & 
\RotText{Lorem Ipsum \& Lorem Ipsum} & \RotText{Lorem Ipsum} & \RotText{Lorem Ipsum} & \RotText{Lorem Ipsum} & \RotText{Lorem Ipsum \& Lorem Ipsum} \\
\hline
Lorem Ipsum     & 
& & X   & & & & & & \\

\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{center}
}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Apologies, I posted the old code. I have since fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

REVISED SOLUTION

One of the problems with your MWE and my earlier tweak thereof was that it did not account for the natural space allocated, by default, between columns, defined by the length `\tabcolsep`.  If narrow is desired, the first thing to do is turn that off, with `\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}`.  Then, there are no `\vspace` tweaks required, and the problem becomes determining the column width that satisfies your requirement.

Here, I strove to make the columns as narrow as possible, again, with no tweaking.  Note, I saved a copy of `\tabcolsep` into `\svtabcolsep`, if I need to reinstate it later.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\let\svtabcolsep\tabcolsep
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\newcommand\RotText[1]{\fontsize{9}{9}\selectfont
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\parbox{2.6cm}{%
\centering#1}}}
\newcolumntype{G}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.35cm}}
\newcolumntype{U}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.62cm}}

\begin{table}[ht]\caption{Lorem Ipsum Table}
\footnotesize
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|G|U|U|U|U|G|G|G|U|}
\hline
 & \multicolumn{9}{c|}{Lorem Ipsum} \\ 
\cline{2-10}

Instruction & \RotText{Lorem Ipsum} & \RotText{Lorem Ipsum \& Lorem Ipsum} & \RotText{Lorem Ipsum \& Lorem Ipsum} & \RotText{Lorem Ipsum \& Lorem Ipsum} & 
\RotText{Lorem Ipsum \& Lorem Ipsum} & \RotText{Lorem Ipsum} & \RotText{Lorem Ipsum} & \RotText{Lorem Ipsum} & \RotText{Lorem Ipsum \& Lorem Ipsum} \\
\hline
Lorem Ipsum     & 
& & X   & & & & & & \\

\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note you could even dispense with the `G` and `U` column types, making them instead `c`, and using a small, finite value of `\tabcolsep` to achieve your goal.

```
\let\svtabcolsep\tabcolsep
\setlength\tabcolsep{.3pt}
\newcolumntype{G}{c}
\newcolumntype{U}{c}
```

Comment: Not to be picky, but the rotated "Lorem Ipsum"s still aren't centered.

Comment: .0625cm wide table columns are distinctly odd, but you are suggesting changing them to be 0cm wide?

Comment: Thanks looks good. I'm not a huge fan of "hacks" with magic numbers. I wish latex packages would have more automatic handling of centering.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  I am not a `tabular` whiz, so in this case, rather than redoing it from scratch, I started with the OP's code, and "tweaked."  Tweaking is under-rated.  I was doing it long before that Miley whats-her-name girl.

Comment: @sphere latex will centre automatically with no problems but not if you ask it to centre visible text in a column that is only half a millimetre wide, it can't centre it so it sticks it out one side/

Comment: @sphere I may have produced the result you desired, but if David Carlisle gives you warning about the approach, it would be wise to pay heed. He authored various `tabular` packages (and maybe `tabular` itself ;^).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  Revised to avoid tweaking.

Comment: @sphere I revised my answer to avoid so-called "hacks."

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, How would I make your final width command to only this table and not other tables within the same document?

Comment: @sphere After the table is done, `\let\tabcolsep\svtabcolsep`.  Alternately, the original `\let\svtabcolsep\tabcolsep` could have been done just inside the `table`, and its effect would evaporate upon leaving the table.

Comment: Also, what does MWE mean?

Comment: @sphere MWE = Minimum Working Example, a short piece of code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`, that demonstrates the essence of the issue.

Comment: Is there any specific reason for using both `\centering` and `\begin{center}`? If there is, what does it achieve which only either of them doesn't?

Comment: @Damitr I had done it so as to make the minimum number of changes to the OP's original code.  However, I see the confusion it can cause, so I haved edited the answer to include only a single instance.

Answer (score 5):

Your box was *far* wider than the specified width of the column, so centreing could not work. Also don't put the table inside a center environment it will float away leaving spurious vertical space from the center display with nothing in it.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\RotText[1]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\parbox{2.6cm}{\centering#1}}}
\newcolumntype{G}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.6cm}}
\newcolumntype{U}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.6cm}}

\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\begin{table}[ht]\caption{Lorem Ipsum Table}
\footnotesize
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|G|U|U|U|U|G|G|G|U|}
\hline
 & \multicolumn{9}{c|}{Lorem Ipsum} \\ 
\cline{2-10}

Instruction & \RotText{Lorem Ipsum} & \RotText{Lorem Ipsum \& Lorem Ipsum} & \RotText{Lorem Ipsum \& Lorem Ipsum} & \RotText{Lorem Ipsum \& Lorem Ipsum} & 
\RotText{Lorem Ipsum \& Lorem Ipsum} & \RotText{Lorem Ipsum} & \RotText{Lorem Ipsum} & \RotText{Lorem Ipsum} & \RotText{Lorem Ipsum \& Lorem Ipsum} \\
\hline
Lorem Ipsum     & 
& & X   & & & & & & \\

\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, however this doesn't fix my problem. The columns are too wide now. You modified the newcolumntype and when I go back to adjust it, the same problem occurs.

Comment: @sphere well make them smaller (but not as small as you had it which doesn't leave room for visible text at all `.0625cm` is really _very_ narrow. Latex warns on the command line for every overfull box so just reduce the font size till it fits.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to pack them in tight...

[image: table]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\RotText[1]{\fontsize{9}{9}\selectfont \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\parbox{2.6cm}{\centering#1}}}
\newcolumntype{C}{@{\hspace{2pt}}c@{\hspace{1pt}}}

\begin{table}[ht]\caption{Lorem Ipsum Table}
\footnotesize
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|C|C|C|C|C|C|C|C|C|}
\hline
 & \multicolumn{9}{c|}{Lorem Ipsum} \\ 
\cline{2-10}

Instruction & \RotText{Lorem Ipsum} & \RotText{Lorem Ipsum \& Lorem Ipsum} & \RotText{Lorem Ipsum \& Lorem Ipsum} & \RotText{Lorem Ipsum \& Lorem Ipsum} & 
\RotText{Lorem Ipsum \& Lorem Ipsum} & \RotText{Lorem Ipsum} & \RotText{Lorem Ipsum} & \RotText{Lorem Ipsum} & \RotText{Lorem Ipsum \& Lorem Ipsum} \\
\hline
Lorem Ipsum     & 
& & X   & & & & & & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\lipsum

\end{document}
```