# vertical alignment of a turned cell

Tags: tables, rotating

I know using turn command and a sample code like this:

```
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{turn}{90} Supervised Learning \end{turn}}
```

we can rotate a text inside a cell, however, I couldn't find a way to vertically center this rotated text. Any suggestions is appreciated.

Here is the sample MWE:

```
\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.5cm}|c|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{8cm}|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Classification} & References \\ \hline
        %\multirow{2}{*}{{\begin{turn}{90}Supervised Learning\end{turn}}}   
        \multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Supervised Learning}} 
\end{tabular}
    \caption{A Classification}
    \label{tab:Machine_Learning_models}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe some here know this package ... however, to other will help a MWE (small complete document, which we can compile), which will show your problem.

Comment: my bad, it was called `rotating`

Comment: I have updated the question with a MWE

Comment: Your subject and objective of your updated question is radically different from what you asked originally. Instead of editing an existing question and changing its content dramatically, you should consider leaving the original query unchanged and posting a second, *new* query to address the new subject material. If nothing else, this approach would avoid rendering the answer that was addressed the initial version of your query meaningless and inapplicable.

Comment: My question was on how to vertically center a rotated text and my question is still that one.

Comment: @Amir - I've deleted my answer. It is obviously of no relevance to your highly modified query.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. This has been driving me crazy for hours. Even here doesn't work: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166482/how-to-horizontally-align-rotated-text-in-a-table

Comment: @Mico, I have created a new question with full code here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326915/vertically-align-a-multirow-text-which-has-been-rotated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

since your question seems to be unstable system ... i'm afraid that my answer will miss your point as it was Mico answer (which finish with deletion) :-( )

anyway, for exercise:

- your rotated text is taller than rest of table, so it can not bo properly centered
- easier way to rotate cell content is use `\rothead` macro from `makecell` package (for which you need to define cell height)
- vertically centering in `multirow` cell needs some manual tweaking

with this (and expand the table) I obtain the following result:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{array,makecell,multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
    \settowidth\rotheadsize{Supervised Learning}
    \begin{tabular}{| l | c |
                     >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{8cm}|}
    \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Classification}    &   References  \\ \hline
\multirow{8}{*}[1.5ex]{\rothead{Supervised Learning}}  
        &                               &  1            \\ \cline{2-3}
        &                               &  2            \\ \cline{2-3}
        &                               &  3            \\ \cline{2-3}
        &                               &  4            \\ \cline{2-3}
        &                               &  5            \\ \cline{2-3}
        &                               &  6            \\ \cline{2-3}
        &                               &  7            \\ \cline{2-3}
        &                               &  8            \\ \hline                \end{tabular}
\caption{A Classification}
    \label{tab:Machine_Learning_models}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
Font size of text in `\rothead` is determined by `\headfont` macro. Default value is `\footnotesize`. It can be changed by

```
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
```

(or whatever size, font family and shape you like). Considering above change of font size, the relvant part of MWE become:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{array,makecell,multirow}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}% <-- added

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
    \settowidth\rotheadsize{\theadfont Supervised Learning}% <-- changed
    \begin{tabular}{| l | c |
                     >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{8cm}|}
    \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Classification}    &   References  \\ \hline
\multirow{8}{*}{\rothead{Supervised Learning}}% <-- changed
% further is the same as in above MWE
```

and table will looks as follows:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for suggesting `makecell` package. Could you ellaborate more on the `\settowidth\rotheadsize{Supervised Learning}` and that `[1.5ex]` in the command.

Comment: and the other thing is that it seems to reduce the text size tho I have plenty of space to have it the normal size. Should I manually increase it ?

Comment: all is explained in answer ...`\settowidth\rotheadsize{Supervised Learning}` determine the length of text, which rotated should fit into cell. i.e. determine cell height. `[1.ex]` in `multirow` is manual adjustment of vertical position of cell content. sorry, i do not understand the second comment. which size is reduced? if you like to have table width equal to text width (i guessing) than the best way to achieve this is use of `tabularx` instead of `table` where instead `p{...}` you use `X` column type.

Comment: Thanks @Zarko. My 2nd question was about the text of the `{Supervised Learning}` is now being reduced in font size despite having enough of space in the column. The vertical alignment is OK now after manually setting [1.ex]

Comment: Indeed, the fonts for vertical text is smaller. It is defined by `\theadfont` which default size is `\footnotesize`. to increase it you need to add `\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}`( or whatever size, font family and shape you like). I will edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Zarko for clarification. Just one thing and it is the issue I have by setting determine cell height to some extreme values such as -10 or 20, i.e., `[-10ex]`. This is needed to center the text, but this will put empty lines of ex for the first nested row. Any ideas why ? To clarify for on your given MWE, it will add empty line at the end of the your first row which has nested by Supervised Learning and beneath Classification.

Comment: I have tested all three rotation methods (`turn`, `rothead` and `rotatebox`) and all has the same problem with setting high values. Apparently your approach didn't solve the question. Setting `\multirow{8}{*}[<ANY_DIGIT>ex]{\rothead{text}}`  is only good enough till the threshold of the first nested row (the height of the 1st nested row) for all mentioned methods. Any values more than that will cuz empty lines. :|

Comment: all my rest show, that `rothead` work as advertised. if you not satisfied with this, than consider to redesign you table so, that rotating text is no needed (or invent/write new package which will work better).

Comment: If you fill up your nested rows on column 2 with so many text, you will see what the problem is. I guess it has nothing to do with wither of the packages but with that cell height alignment of the `multirow` package. So your answer still holds @Zarko

Comment: One option (when the rotated text is to tall) is to broke rotated text into two (or more) lines (if this acceptable option).