# Vertically align a multirow text which has been rotated

Tags: tables, rotating, multirow

I know using turn command and a sample code like this:

```
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{turn}{90} Supervised Learning \end{turn}}
```

we can rotate a text inside a cell, however, I couldn't find a way to vertically center this rotated text when we have `multirow`. Any suggestions is appreciated.

```
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{A Classification }
    \begin{tabular}{|c|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2.2cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{10.5cm}|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Classification} & References \\ \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{{\begin{turn}{90}Supervised Learning\end{turn}}}   
       % \multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\parbox{.6cm}{\centering{Supervised Learning}}}}   
        & Bayesian &

        \\ \cline{2-3}
        & Linear  &

        \\ \cline{2-3}
        & Decision Trees &

        \\ \cline{2-3}
        & Neural Networks / Genetic Algorithm &

        \\ \cline{2-3}
        & Others  &

        \\ \cline{2-3}
        \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{{\begin{turn}{90} Unsupervised  \end{turn}}} 
        & Clustering &

        \\ \cline{2-3}
        \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{{\begin{turn}{90} Others \end{turn}}} 
        & Reinforcement Learning  &

        \\  \cline{2-3}
        & Graph-based & 

        \\  \cline{2-3}
        & Statistical Methods &

        \\ \cline{2-3}
        \hline
        %\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Statistical Methods} & 
        \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \label{tab:Machine_Learning_models}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Could we have a fully compilable code that we can play with?

Comment: Updated the question @Bernard

Comment: One point is not clear: `unsupervised` and `others` have to be in front of different series of rows?

Comment: Yes. They are the parent categories

Comment: In this case there's no room for `unsupervised`: it is in front of a single row.