# Write vertically over several cells

Tags: tables, rotating, multirow

I have a table with an empty first column. All the other columns are filled with text or formulae. I want to write the words "DC grid" vertically over the whole first column except for the first two rows (which are already used) without changing the overall look of my table.

The problem is, I cannot simply use `\multirow` because I want to write over several cells (not just rows). I tried to do tables inside tables (nested tables) but I can't get rid of the additional space added by the nested table.

Here is my table (I want to write "DC grid" vertically in the empty first column):

[image]

```
\begin{table}[!htbp]%200pts de large
\centerline{\resizebox{0.90\linewidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}
{|>{\centering}p{15pt}|>{\centering}p{25pt}|>{\centering}p{55pt}|>{\centering}p{20pt}|>{\centering}p{23pt}|>{\centering}p{70pt}|}\hline %\pm
%
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Eigenvalues}}} & \textbf{Freq. (Hz)} & \textbf{Damp. ratio} & \centering \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Dominant states}}\tabularnewline\hline
%
 & \multirow{1}{*}{$\lambda_{dc_{1,2}}$} & \multirow{1}{*}{$-56.7 \pm j2130$} & \multirow{1}{*}{$339$} & \multirow{1}{*}{$0.027$} & $X_{p_1}$, $X_{p_2}$, $X_{p_3}$,  \tabularnewline\cline{2-5}
%
 & \multirow{1}{*}{$\lambda_{dc_{2,3}}$} & \multirow{1}{*}{$-56.7 - j2011$} & \multirow{1}{*}{$320$} & \multirow{1}{*}{$0.028$} & $\Delta u_{s_1}$, $\Delta u_{s_2}$, $\Delta u_{s_3}$ \tabularnewline\cline{2-5}
%
 & \multirow{1}{*}{$\lambda_{dc_{5,6}}$} & \multirow{1}{*}{$-60.0 \pm j1426$} & \multirow{1}{*}{$227$} & \multirow{1}{*}{$0.040$} &  $\Delta u_{s_4}$, $\Delta u_{s_5}$\tabularnewline\cline{2-6}
%
 & \multirow{4}{*}{$\lambda_{dc_{7,8}}$} & \multirow{4}{*}{$-57 \pm j1223$} & \multirow{4}{*}{$195$} & \multirow{4}{*}{$0.047$} & $i_{l_{1_1}}$, $i_{l_{2_1}}$, $i_{l_{1_4}}$, $i_{l_{2_4}}$, $i_{l_{1_5}}$, $i_{l_{2_5}}$\vspace{0.4mm}, $\Delta u_{s_1}$, $\Delta u_{s_2}$, $\Delta u_{s_3}$, $\Delta u_{s_4}$, $\Delta u_{s_5}$\tabularnewline\cline{2-6} 
%
 & \multirow{1}{*}{$\lambda_{dc_{9}}$} & \multirow{1}{*}{$-117.1$} & \multirow{1}{*}{ -- } & \multirow{1}{*}{ -- } & $i_{l_{1_1}}$, $i_{l_{2_1}}$, $i_{l_{1_2}}$,\tabularnewline\cline{2-5}
%
 & \multirow{1}{*}{$\lambda_{dc_{10}}$} & \multirow{1}{*}{$-4.497$} & \multirow{1}{*}{ -- } & \multirow{1}{*}{ -- } & $i_{l_{2_2}}$, $i_{l_{1_3}}$, $i_{l_{2_3}}$,\tabularnewline\cline{2-5}
%
 & \multirow{1}{*}{$\lambda_{dc_{11}}$} & \multirow{1}{*}{$-4.476$} & \multirow{1}{*}{ -- } & \multirow{1}{*}{ -- } & $i_{l_{1_4}}$, $i_{l_{2_4}}$, $i_{l_{1_5}}$,\tabularnewline\cline{2-5}
%
 & \multirow{1}{*}{$\lambda_{dc_{12}}$} & \multirow{1}{*}{$-0.604$} & \multirow{1}{*}{ -- } & \multirow{1}{*}{ -- } & $i_{l_{2_5}}$, $i_{l_{1_6}}$, $i_{l_{2_6}}$,\tabularnewline\cline{1-6}
%
%
\end{tabular}}}\vspace{3mm}
\caption{Modal Analysis of the 5-Terminal HVDC Grid}\label{tab5}\end{table}%
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Do you mean you want to write ‘DC grid’  over several consecutive columns?

Comment: Thank you Andrew!
Bernard, I want to write 'DC grid' over all the consecutive rows of the first column

Comment: related: [Rotating text at the side of a table?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/169605/579)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
\documentclass{Article}
\usepackage{multirow,graphicx,array}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering                              %% use this instead of \centerline
\resizebox{0.90\linewidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}
{|>{\centering}p{15pt}|>{\centering}p{25pt}|>{\centering}p{63pt}|>{\centering}p{26pt}|
           >{\centering}p{33pt}|>{\centering}p{83pt}|}\hline %\pm
%
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Eigenvalues}}} & \textbf{Freq. (Hz)} & \textbf{Damp. ratio} & \centering \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Dominant states}}\tabularnewline\hline
%
 & \multirow{1}{*}{$\lambda_{dc_{1,2}}$} & \multirow{1}{*}{$-56.7 \pm j2130$} & \multirow{1}{*}{$339$} & \multirow{1}{*}{$0.027$} & $X_{p_1}$, $X_{p_2}$, $X_{p_3}$,  \tabularnewline\cline{2-5}
%
 & \multirow{1}{*}{$\lambda_{dc_{2,3}}$} & \multirow{1}{*}{$-56.7 - j2011$} & \multirow{1}{*}{$320$} & \multirow{1}{*}{$0.028$} & $\Delta u_{s_1}$, $\Delta u_{s_2}$, $\Delta u_{s_3}$ \tabularnewline\cline{2-5}
%
 & \multirow{1}{*}{$\lambda_{dc_{5,6}}$} & \multirow{1}{*}{$-60.0 \pm j1426$} & \multirow{1}{*}{$227$} & \multirow{1}{*}{$0.040$} &  $\Delta u_{s_4}$, $\Delta u_{s_5}$\tabularnewline\cline{2-6}
%
 & \multirow{4}{*}{$\lambda_{dc_{7,8}}$} & \multirow{4}{*}{$-57 \pm j1223$} & \multirow{4}{*}{$195$} & \multirow{4}{*}{$0.047$} & $i_{l_{1_1}}$, $i_{l_{2_1}}$, $i_{l_{1_4}}$, $i_{l_{2_4}}$, $i_{l_{1_5}}$, $i_{l_{2_5}}$\vspace{0.4mm}, $\Delta u_{s_1}$, $\Delta u_{s_2}$, $\Delta u_{s_3}$, $\Delta u_{s_4}$, $\Delta u_{s_5}$\tabularnewline\cline{2-6}
%
 & \multirow{1}{*}{$\lambda_{dc_{9}}$} & \multirow{1}{*}{$-117.1$} & \multirow{1}{*}{ -- } & \multirow{1}{*}{ -- } & $i_{l_{1_1}}$, $i_{l_{2_1}}$, $i_{l_{1_2}}$,\tabularnewline\cline{2-5}
%
 & \multirow{1}{*}{$\lambda_{dc_{10}}$} & \multirow{1}{*}{$-4.497$} & \multirow{1}{*}{ -- } & \multirow{1}{*}{ -- } & $i_{l_{2_2}}$, $i_{l_{1_3}}$, $i_{l_{2_3}}$,\tabularnewline\cline{2-5}
%
 & \multirow{1}{*}{$\lambda_{dc_{11}}$} & \multirow{1}{*}{$-4.476$} & \multirow{1}{*}{ -- } & \multirow{1}{*}{ -- } & $i_{l_{1_4}}$, $i_{l_{2_4}}$, $i_{l_{1_5}}$,\tabularnewline\cline{2-5}
%
\multirow{-11}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{DC Grid}}     %% change 11 as you add further rows and put this in the last row.
 & \multirow{1}{*}{$\lambda_{dc_{12}}$} & \multirow{1}{*}{$-0.604$} & \multirow{1}{*}{ -- } & \multirow{1}{*}{ -- } & $i_{l_{2_5}}$, $i_{l_{1_6}}$, $i_{l_{2_6}}$,\tabularnewline\cline{1-6}
%
%
\end{tabular}}%\vspace{3mm}
\caption{Modal Analysis of the 5-Terminal HVDC Grid}\label{tab5}
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly! Thank you so much, it works! I need to understand why it works with a negative value in multirow though  
  
Thank you again!

Answer (score 5):

You can have a much simpler code, using the `makecell` package. The `caption` package helps getting a caption like the image in the O.P.'s question. However, I suggest another layout using `booktabs`,  with no vertical lines. The code below shows both layouts:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow,graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{makecell, booktabs}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cellalign{lc}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{uppercase}{\MakeUppercase{#1}~\Roman{table}}
\captionsetup{textfont=sc, labelformat=uppercase, labelsep=newline}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{table}{3}
  \begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering \makegapedcells%%
\resizebox{0.90\linewidth}{!}{%
 $ \begin{array}{|>{\centering}p{15pt}|c|c|c|c|>{\centering\arraybackslash $}p{90pt}<{$}|}
 \hline %
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\thead{\text{Eigenvalues}}}& \thead{\text{Freq.}\\ \text{(Hz)}} & \thead{\text{Damp.}\\ \text{ratio}} & \thead{\text{Dominant states}} \\
\hline
 & \lambda_{dc_{1,2}} & -56.7 \pm j2130 & 339 & 0.027 & \multirowcell{4}[0.3ex]{
 X_{p_1}, X_{p_2}, X_{p_3} , \\ \Delta u_{s_1}, \Delta u_{s_2}, \Delta u_{s_3}, \\ \Delta u_{s_4}, \Delta u_{s_5}} \\
\cline{2-5}
%
 & \lambda_{dc_{2,3}} & -56.7 - j2011 & 320 & 0.028 & \\
 \cline{2-5}
%
 & \lambda_{dc_{5,6}} & -60.0 \pm j1426 & 227 & 0.040 & \\
 \cline{2-6}
%
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{DC Grid} & \lambda_{dc_{7,8}} & -57 \pm j1223 & 195 & 0.047 & \makecell{ i_{l_{1_1}}, i_{l_{2_1}}, i_{l_{1_4}}, i_{l_{2_4}},\\ i_{l_{1_5}}, i_{l_{2_5}}, \Delta u_{s_1}, \Delta u_{s_2},\\ \Delta u_{s_3}, \Delta u_{s_4}, \Delta u_{s_5}\bigskip} \\
 \cline{2-6}
%
 & \lambda_{dc_{9}} & -117.1 & \textendash & \textendash & \multirowcell{4}[-1ex]{ i_{l_{1_1}}, i_{l_{2_1}}, i_{l_{1_2}}, i_{l_{2_2}}, \\ i_{l_{1_3}}, i_{l_{2_3}}, i_{l_{1_4}}, i_{l_{2_4}}, \\ i_{l_{1_5}}, i_{l_{2_5}}, i_{l_{1_6}}, i_{l_{2_6}}} \\
 \cline{2-5}
%
 & \lambda_{dc_{10}} & -4.497 & \textendash & \textendash & \\
 \cline{2-5}
%
 & \lambda_{dc_{11}} & -4.476 & \textendash & \textendash & \\
 \cline{2-5}
%
 & \lambda_{dc_{12}} & -0.604 & \textendash & \textendash & \\
 \cline{1-6}%
\end{array} $}%
\caption{Modal Analysis of the 5-Terminal HVDC Grid}\label{tab5}
\end{table}%
\vskip 0.5cm

  \begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering \makegapedcells%%
\resizebox{0.90\linewidth}{!}{%
 $ \begin{array}{c*{4}{c}>{\centering\arraybackslash $}p{90pt}<{$}}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{\text{Eigenvalues}}}& \thead{\text{Freq.}\\ \text{(Hz)}} & \thead{\text{Damp.}\\ \text{ratio}} & \thead{\text{Dominant states}} \\
 \addlinespace[-1ex]
\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{2-6}
 & \lambda_{dc_{1,2}} & -56.7 \pm j2130 & 339 & 0.027 & \multirowcell{4}[0.5ex]{
 X_{p_1}, X_{p_2}, X_{p_3} , \\ \Delta u_{s_1}, \Delta u_{s_2}, \Delta u_{s_3}, \\ \Delta u_{s_4}, \Delta u_{s_5}} \\
 & \lambda_{dc_{2,3}} & -56.7 - j2011 & 320 & 0.028 & \\
%
 & \lambda_{dc_{5,6}} & -60.0 \pm j1426 & 227 & 0.040 & \\
 \cmidrule(lr){2-6}
%
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{DC Grid} & \lambda_{dc_{7,8}} & -57 \pm j1223 & 195 & 0.047 & \makecell{ i_{l_{1_1}}, i_{l_{2_1}}, i_{l_{1_4}}, i_{l_{2_4}},\\ i_{l_{1_5}}, i_{l_{2_5}}, \Delta u_{s_1}, \Delta u_{s_2},\\ \Delta u_{s_3}, \Delta u_{s_4}, \Delta u_{s_5}} \\
 \cmidrule(lr){2-6}
%
 & \lambda_{dc_{9}} & -117.1 & \textendash & \textendash & \multirowcell{4}[-1ex]{ i_{l_{1_1}}, i_{l_{2_1}}, i_{l_{1_2}}, i_{l_{2_2}}, \\ i_{l_{1_3}}, i_{l_{2_3}}, i_{l_{1_4}}, i_{l_{2_4}}, \\ i_{l_{1_5}}, i_{l_{2_5}}, i_{l_{1_6}}, i_{l_{2_6}}} \\
%
 & \lambda_{dc_{10}} & -4.497 & \textendash & \textendash & \\
%
 & \lambda_{dc_{11}} & -4.476 & \textendash & \textendash & \\
%
 & \lambda_{dc_{12}} & -0.604 & \textendash & \textendash & \\
 \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{2-6}
\end{array} $}%
\caption{Modal Analysis of the 5-Terminal HVDC Grid}\label{tab5-a}
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]